# Is there a way to make a page in the Kindle app less brighter than the options available within the app?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have my bright setting on the lowest in my app and my phone is at the lowest possible brightnes too but I find it too bright to read a page in the Kindle app in the dark.  Is there any way to lower the brightness? I only find that the Android stock browser's lowest brightness setting to be bearable in the dark; even the lowest possible brightness setting in Chrome is too bright.  Is there some radical way to make the brightness in the Kindle lower than the default?

Samsung Galaxy S3
4.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To break the upper/lower limits of device settings, you'd most likely need to tweak your ROM, which requires the device to be rooted. I know there are some solutions for volume limits around ("booster"), so I won't rule out they do exist here as well.

To work around system settings at the "lower end", as it is your intention, you might e.g. want to take a look at [Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor):

> Applies a shade that acts as a dimmer to ensure your eyes don't hurt. Far more powerful than Android's built-in brightness setting. Great for low-light gaming, web browsing, and eBook reading. It even saves battery life for AMOLED displays!

So this app uses a trick by adding a semi-transparent layer on top of what's displayed, which makes the display appear "darker".

Then there's also [Night Mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.bbarao.nightmode), which has a similar goal (and uses a similar method to reach it):

> Night Mode's main goal is to reduce the brightness of your screen lower than you can achieve with the default settings.
>
> This application applies an overlay filter that acts as a dimmer to darken the screen and ensure your eyes don't hurt.

Pick your choice -- or check for another. Where there are two, there might be more ([Super Dimmer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dberm22.SuperDimmer), [Screen Dimmer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sebmorand.brightcom), [Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.labs.quantative.screenfilter), ...). A Playstore search will be your friend here (note that that's also all what I did -- I didn't use any of those solutions myself, so no guarantees :)

Comment: I quite like [Twilight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.lux&hl=en) - basically overlays a translucent slightly orange layer on the screen at night. Very similar to [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) for the pc, although slightly buggy at times

Answer (score 8):

You can change the brightness in the Kindle app by touching the "Aa" icon near the upper right. This will bring up the font, size and brightness settings, which you can then adjust to your liking.

[image: Amazon Kindle brightness settings]

Comment: I have that at the lowest setting possible already. And, my phone is at the lowest setting too.  I was looking for something to alter this...

Comment: How can you go any lower than the lowest setting!

Comment: I've heard some people say you could through the OS but I'm not sure about any details...

Comment: Maybe, but that's a completely different question than the one you asked.

Comment: This is great! It was very frustrating to see that the system brightness did not coincide with my book's brightness. On this screen you can also say that the brightness SHOULD match the system's brightness.

Answer (score 0):

change the background colour to sepia which will appear less bright or even wear sunglasses!

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a more, um... technical solution than "wear sunglasses".

Comment: @Chahk:  Sunglasses are an easy solution.  It takes only seconds to put them on or take them off; that's probably less time than it takes to enable a screen filter app.  If the OP has a pair of sunglasses handy, this is a quicker and better solution than using a screen filter app.  I've upvoted this answer.

Comment: Same thought here Upvoted